# Unable to connect Twemproxy using StackExchange redis in C#

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, twemproxy

I am trying to execute C# code below with StackExchange redis using IP address of the TWEMPROXY server and it gives error below:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException' occurred in
>   StackExchange.Redis.dll
>
> Additional information: It was not possible to connect to the redis
>   server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable
>   AbortOnConnectFail. SocketFailure on PING

But, when I use local host it works fine and stores data in local Redis cache

The code sample with 'localhost' is as below:

```
using System;
namespace WinRedis
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            new MainClass().testingCache();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public void testingCache()
        {
            SimpleCache<User> cache = new RedisCache<User>("mycache", "localhost:6379");
            cache.Put ("user1", new User () { Name = "test", Email = "test@email.com", Password = "secured" });
            User user = cache.Get("user1");
            Console.WriteLine(user);
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    class User{
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public string Email { set; get; }
        public string Password {set;get;}

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "User(Name: " + Name + ", Email: " + Email + ", Password: " + Password + ")";
        }
    }
}


using System;
using StackExchange.Redis;

namespace WinRedis
{
    public class RedisCache<T> : SimpleCache<T>
    {
        private ConnectionMultiplexer redisConnection = null;
        private IDatabase redis = null;
        private string name = null;
        public RedisCache(string name = "redis-cache",
            string connectionOptions = "localhost:6379")
        {
            this.redisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionOptions); 
            this.redis = redisConnection.GetDatabase ();
            this.name = name;

        }

        public T Get(string key)
        {
            byte[] result = this.redis.HashGet (name, key);

            if (result == null)
                return default(T);
            else
                return result.Deserialize<T>();

        }

        public void Put(string key, T value)
        {
            this.redis.HashSet (name, key, value.SerializeToByteArray() );
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            this.redisConnection.Close ();
        }
    }
}
```

For the same code above, when I replace localhost with TWEMPROXY IP address it gives error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Configuration.md#twemproxy

suggests that maybe something like this might work... maybe

```
var options = new ConfigurationOptions
{
    EndPoints = { "your_endpoint:port" },
    Proxy = Proxy.Twemproxy
};

ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options);
```